# Mocha in the browser: How to get a report using chai.assert

Tags: javascript, testing, assert, mocha.js, chai

I can't get Mocha to produce output when using chai.assert.
http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/244PT/6/

```
var assert = chai.assert();
mocha.setup('bdd');

describe('Kata', function() {
    it('should return...', function() {
        assert.equal(true, true, 'Truthy values should be treated equal.');
    });
});

mocha.run();
```

It works perfectly with chai.should and chai.expect.
http://jsfiddle.net/web5me/244PT/#base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are calling assert wrong, have you tried

```
var assert = chai.assert;
```

Comment: No problem. Happens to everybody!